# How to initiate authentication for replica set - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

There is a replica set without authentication.
I want to create its authentication for first time.

I do as following:

```
1- create [administrator user][1]
2- restarting all member with option `auth=true`
3- login as aadministrator to one member of replica set
4- trying to create user "db.addUser(...)"
```

but when I want to create user, it throw exception of `couldn't add user: not master at src/mongo/shell/db.js:128`

What should I do? is it possible initiate security in existing replica set Or I should, remove replica set and rebuild it, after setting authentication.

Comment: Are you adding users on the Primary node or Secondary?

Comment: That's good. What permissions did you assign the newly created admin user?

Comment: db.addUser( { user: "dba", pwd: "3", roles: [ "userAdminAnyDatabase" ] } )

Comment: Ok that is fine too, I "think" I see your issue. How are you logging into the mongo client? Are you using the following command? $ mongo admin -u <username> -p <password> Important to note here is that you connect to the **admin** db first.

Comment: i connected as: mongo admin --port 27050 -u dba -p 3 . but not work

Comment: When you connect, as you seeing "PRIMARY>" on the mongo client console?

Comment: Ok, then you have an issue with authentication. I would suggest turning auth off, and restarting mongod.

Comment: i did but not work. I did this steps member by member, not workes too.

Answer (score 5):

If replica set already exists, you need to find the primary node, add a user with "root" role, and for each database add a user with admin/writeAndRead/read role, and/or add an admin user for all databases.

```
use admin

db.createUser({ user: "rootUser", pwd: "rootPass", roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ] })

db.createUser({ user: "admin", pwd: "adminPass", roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ] })

use otherDb

db.createUser({ user: "rwUser", pwd: "rwUserPass", roles: [{ role: "readWrite", db: "otherDb" }] })
```

Wait until sync all replica nodes. Set auth=yes on each mongod.conf file (this will force each client to use user/pass).

If you want (not required), to add keyFile to enforce extra security steps between all replica set, you can create this file, copy between each node and enable keyFile option inside each mongod.conf file, but this is only to force replica set nodes to know a secret between them and start talking, not for client applications.

Finally restart the primary node wait for new primary election and continue restarting all nodes inside replica set.

Couple of useful links for create secret key file http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-with-auth/#create-the-key-file-to-be-used-by-each-member-of-the-replica-set
and more details for the mongodb v2.6 version
http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-with-auth/#create-the-key-file-to-be-used-by-each-member-of-the-replica-set

Comment: this is for 2.6? is there auth for mongo 4?

Answer (score 4):

though replica set exists, it is not a master or master has not set.
you might haven't init replica set yet.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/

```
> rs.initiate()
> rs.add("secondary-host:27017")
> rs.add("more-hosts-if-exist:27017")
```

and then you could create user.

```
> db.createUser({ user: "root", pwd: "rootpw", roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ] })
> db.createUser({user: "useradmin", pwd: "adminpw", roles: [ { role: "userAdmin", db: "admin" } ] })
```

like @Aaron Castro's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are configuring a replicaSet, I believe you need to use the keyFile option rather than auth=Yes.  This will allow the nodes in the replicaSet to communicate with eachother once authentication is enabled.

Check this doc.  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication

Comment: ...**and then** initiate the replica set as @Kennyhyun stated